# DryIoc RegisterInitializer for logging resolution errors?

Tags: dryioc

Looking at the documentation for DryIoc I see there is a way to register an initializer func that could be used to log successful resolutions.

Is there anyway to log failed resolutions using RegisterInitializer or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no direct way to log every possible error per resolution, except by catching the `ContainerException`.

But it is possible to detect potential errors beforehand:

```
var errors = container.VerifyResolutions();
```

Here is the [docs](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/ErrorDetectionAndResolution).

If you interested in unknown registrations  you can add the rule to log unknown via [UnknownServiceResolvers](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RulesAndDefaultConventions#markdown-header-unknownserviceresolvers):

```
container = new Container(rules =>
    rules.WithUnknownServiceResolvers(
       request => {
           Log.Error("Not found: " + request);
           return null;
       }));
```

Possibly, there are other ways: for instance using Decorators to wrap allow-default services. But it strongly depends on your context.